# Migrating A standalone (no AD) Windows 2008 32bit To 2008 64bit

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, upgrade

I have a Windows 2008 Standard 32 bit server running for the sole task of code signing. I need to "upgrade" it to Windows 2008 R2 64 bit. I understand there is no direct upgrade path from 32 to 64 bit. 
Can you recommend a method that would allow me to transfer users / settings with the following conditions:

1. Users are transferred
2. The certificates in the users cert stores are transferred (this is not a deal breaker if not possible)
3. Server roles? (again, a nice-to-have)

Finally, If possible, I don't want to have to setup another physical box to do this. e.g. Id like to run some magic program, it backup to a disk, then install Windows 2008 R2 and restore everything.

anything like this possible? If not, what are my options? Obviously Id like to avoid manually creating everything again.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `I don't want to have to setup another physical box to do this. e.g. Id like to run some magic program, it backup to a disk, then install Windows 2008 R2 and restore everything` - That isn't possible. You're going to need to stand up a new server to become a new Domain Controller in the domain.

Comment: As I mentioned in the title, Its not a domain controller.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's going to have to be a fresh install.

I think it's unlikely that you're going to be able to automate this process, and I think it would be a case of setting everything up manually.
Personally, I would recommend a new box, but failing that, a new hard drive would be the best solution.

That way, if there is anything you've missed off, you can at least revert back to the old OS.

Obviously take a backup first

Answer (score 0):

You can save the users with "addusers" get it off ms site, by saving to a csv file etc. then restore them fairly easily
You can get the shares (if you have many) out of the registry, just find the relevant areas and back it up.

Id also recommend using another drive if youve got one machine, and if you take that route make lots of notes, text backups and save it all first so you can bring it all over

If its a Domain controller you can get the info from others DCs (various to do)

Note sure on certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the certificate authority database also.  Here is the in-depth [Microsoft Technet documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ee126170.aspx) for that.  You will want to read it carefully.  The table on the first page of the link indicates that migrating from 2008 32-bit to 2008 R2 64-bit is supported.